# How can I avoid a deadlock between these two SQL statements?

Tags: sql, deadlock, sql-server-2005-express, nolock

I have two stored procedures running in separate threads, running on SQL Server 2005. One procedure inserts new rows into a set of tables and the other procedure deletes old data from the same set of tables. These procedures are running into a deadlock on the tables **DLevel** and **Model**. Here is the schema:

[image: Scrollbar Image]
<sub>(source: [barramsoft.com](http://www.barramsoft.com/pub/images/DeadLock2.jpg))</sub>

> Table **DFile**: Primary Key = DFileID
>   Table **DLevel**: Primary Key = DLevelID, Foreign Key: DFileID
>   Table **Model**: Primary Key = ModelID, Foreign Key: DFileID
>   Table **ELement**: Primary key = ElementID, Foreign Key1: DFileID, Foreign Key2: DLevelID

I have isolated the exact two SQL statements (one from each stored procedure) that are causing the deadlock. I have seen the deadlock reported by either of the procedures. I use top (1000) in both cases and both statements are executed in a loop until they complete with no rows left to delete/insert.

**SQL Statement 1:**

```
while (...)
begin
    delete top (1000) from DLevel where DFileID = @fileID1
    ...
end
```

**SQL Statement 2:**

```
while (...)
begin
    insert into Element (ElementID, DFileID, LevelNum, ...)
       select top (1000) el.ElementID, el.DFileID, el.LevelNum, ...
       from   ElementLoader el with (nolock)
              left outer join Element e with (nolock)
                   on e.ElementID = el.ElementID
       where  el.DFileID = @fileID2
       and    e.ElementID is null
       order  by el.ElementID
    ...
end
```

Note: The values for *@fileID1* and *@fileID2* are always guaranteed to be different. DLevel table has on average approx. 60 rows for a single *DFileID* and thus would complete deletion of all rows in a single pass.

How can I avoid a deadlock between these two SQL statements?

**Edit 1:**
Rewritten to better clarify issue; added image; simplified SQL and removed join to DLevel table, which did not contribute to deadlock.

**Edit 2:**
Added XML of deadlock graph.
Deadlock now occurs on *Model* table. Similar delete statement and schema for *Model* as for *DLevel* table.

```
<deadlock victim="process2bae38">
    <process-list>
        <process id="process2bae38" taskpriority="0" logused="4760" waitresource="PAGE: 11:1:1946" waittime="46" ownerId="4127445" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2010-06-24T16:19:00.107" XDES="0xffffffff90552ae0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="14252" status="suspended" spid="58" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" transcount="2" lastbatchstarted="2010-06-24T16:19:00.107" lastbatchcompleted="2010-06-24T16:19:00.107" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="LT0103" hostpid="1668" loginname="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4127445" currentdb="11" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="CadExplorer5.dbo.pCleanUpOldFiles" line="364" stmtstart="23718" stmtend="23834" sqlhandle="0x03000b00fb1c2229b1a7f7009f9d00000100000000000000">
delete top (@batchSize) from Model where DFileID = @fileID     </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 11 Object Id = 690101499]    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process2c95b8" taskpriority="0" logused="283388" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594039304192 (8100bdf15e8b)" waittime="78" ownerId="4127412" transactionname="INSERT" lasttranstarted="2010-06-24T16:19:00.103" XDES="0xffffffff81d5ef18" lockMode="S" schedulerid="2" kpid="8460" status="suspended" spid="63" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" transcount="2" lastbatchstarted="2010-06-24T16:18:59.413" lastbatchcompleted="2010-06-24T16:18:59.413" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="LT0103" hostpid="1668" loginname="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4127412" currentdb="11" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="CadExplorer5.dbo.pLoadElements" line="288" stmtstart="28796" stmtend="33194" sqlhandle="0x03000b00a689fe2b2c5107019f9d00000100000000000000">
insert into Element (
                        ElementID, DFileID, ModelID, ElementTypeID, CADElementID,
                        ParentID,
                        LevelNum,
                        Depth, NumChildren,
                        Color, Weight, Style, Xlo, Ylo, Zlo, Xhi, Yhi, Zhi,
                        Diagonal, XCenter,
                        BitFlags, ElementModTime
                        )
                  select top (@batchSize)
                        el.ElementID, el.DFileID, el.ModelID, el.ElementTypeID, el.CADElementID,
                        parent.ElementID as ParentID,
                        (case when el.LoaderType = 1 and et.IsGraphical = 1 then el.LevelAttrib else null end) as LevelNum,
                        --l.LevelNum,
                        el.Depth, el.NumChildren,
                        el.Color, el.Weight, el.Style, el.Xlo, el.Ylo, el.Zlo, el.Xhi, el.Yhi, el.Zhi,
                        el.Diagonal, el.XCenter,     </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 11 Object Id = 738101670]    </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1946" dbid="11" objectname="CadExplorer5.dbo.Element" id="lockffffffff86ffd080" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594039107584">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2c95b8" mode="IX"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2bae38" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </pagelock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594039304192" dbid="11" objectname="CadExplorer5.dbo.Model" indexname="PK_Model" id="lockffffffff8d66db80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594039304192">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2bae38" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2c95b8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: which version of SQL server ? I bet this is in SQL 2000!!

Comment: Are there any foreign key constraints between DLevel and Element?

Comment: Broken Link: Version is SQL Server 2005 Express.

Comment: AlexKuznetsov: Yes, on DFileID and LevelNum.

Comment: If you add the deadlock graph you would take a lot of guesswork out of the equation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190465.aspx

Comment: @Remus: Thanks for suggestion. I ran the deadlock graph. I get a page lock on "Element" and a key lock on "DLevel". I need to study it further to fully grasp it. I have simplified the SQL and still running into the deadlock.

Comment: @Elan - Can you paste the XML version of the deadlock graph into your question?

Comment: @Martin: Added XML version of deadlock graph.

Comment: @Elan - What is the page lock on? `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id), i.name, p.partition_id  FROM sys.partitions AS p INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id  WHERE p.partition_id = 72057594039107584`

Comment: @Martin - OBJECT_NAME: Element, i.name = PK_Element, p.partition_id = 72057594039107584

Comment: I *think* what is happening is **1** Delete from model requests a shared page lock on Page ID 1946 (PK_Element in CadExplorer5.dbo.Element) that is held by the insert statement. 
It does this as it must read Element to check that the delete won't violate any Foreign Key constraints and leave orphaned records in Element. **2** Insert statement to Element requests a shared key lock on PK_Model (in CadExplorer5.dbo.Model) that is held by the delete statement. It does this as it must check that the insert won't violate any Foreign Key constraints. If so I'm not sure how to prevent this.

Comment: @Martin - Thanks very much for helping me with this. Do you have any suggestions on how I might be able to avoid the deadlock? I tried an exclusive table lock on the Model table prior to executing the delete (thus forcing the insert on Element table to block). This reduced the number of deadlocks greatly, but I am still getting deadlocks!?!

Comment: @Elan - No I don't I'm still trying to learn more about this area myself so take my analysis with a pinch of salt. Hopefully someone else will confirm whether it has any merit! This article discusses a possibly similar issue though http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2007/03/30/blocking-from-foreign-key-constraint-look-ups-clustered-blocks-v-heap-doesn-t-block.aspx.

Comment: If you denormalize and remove all forign keys does this deadlock go away (it looks like its related to the fk constraints)

Comment: @Sam: At this point, it does appear to boil down to the foreign key constraints and I do believe the deadlock would go away if I removed them. I would need test and confirm. It also seems that page locking on the "insert into Element" table is what is causing this. Purging existing data that has foreign keys is hardly an uncommon scenario! There's got to be a solution to this without removing foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 1):

One possible scenario: one connection insert a row in Element, and that row refers to a row in DLevel, and that row in DLevel is being deleted by another connection. Your nolock hint does not apply to foreign keys.

Comment: These statements are executed in separate connections. The rows (of the DLevel table) referenced by the insert and delete statements are always different as the DFileID is different between the two. If the nolock does not apply to foreign keys, then maybe the two statements are running into page locking conflicts. I am aware of turning off row and page locking, but is there any way to force row level locking?

Comment: Removed join to DLevel table in the "insert into Element..." query. Still get the deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

You might try removing the Foreign Key to DLevel.DFileID from the Element table.  Since you have a Primary Key on DLevel.DlevelID and you reference that as a Foreign key in Element, the DFileID foreign key is not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there must be some kind of key violation with delete and insert going at same time..?