# SQL Server lock due to select while inserting

Tags: sql-server

I want to fetch some rows from a table while insertion is being done in that same table. While doing this operation, the table is being locked.

How can I fix this?

kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out the `with (nolock)` lock hint if you don't mind the possibility of dirty reads on your select statements

Comment: The INSERT operation should only lock that it's inserting - not the whole table - unless it inserts a lot of rows (more than 5000) in which case it might do a "lock escalation" and just lock the whole table. Try to insert in group of less than 5000 rows to avoid lock escalation

Comment: Locking and blocking is there to adhere to the consistency principle.  It's a good thing.  I agree with @marc_s, ensure you're not escalating to a table-level lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if you are using `SQL Server 2008`, then there is a provision to hint SQL Server to take `row level lock`.

[Is it possible to force row level locking in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114826/is-it-possible-to-force-row-level-locking-in-sql-server)