# SQL Server Update one row blocking

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL Server and have simple table:

```
Person (ID bigint, Name nvarchar(255))
```

It contains 1000 rows (for example). I'm using this SQL query:

```
Update Person
Set Name = 'Jason' 
Where Id = 100
```

I want to understand how SQL Server will do read/write locking. Will it block one row (which I'm updating) or will it block all `Person` table?

Will the situation change if I will use query?

```
Update Person
Set Name = 'Jason' 
Where Name = 'Piter'
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114826/is-it-possible-to-force-row-level-locking-in-sql-server)..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read this [SQL Server Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx#Lock_Basics).

In general, your query will take update lock on the row which is updated, unless server decides that it should use [lock escalation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and locks page or table/index.